# Send ajaxform data to multiple email addresses

Tags: php, ajax, mailto, ajaxform

I wish to send a copy of the data filled out by the visitor to myself and the other copy to the visitor. Please advice!

My email is myemail@mysite.com while the visitor's email is `$email`

This code is as seen below:

```
// Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "myemail@mysite.com, .$email";
```

I'm not getting any results after hitting the submit button!

I'll be very grateful!

```
   <?php
// My modifications to mailer script from:
// http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
// Added input sanitizing to prevent injection

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "myemail@mysite.com, .$email";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

?>

Comment: instead use `$recipient = "myemail@mysite.com, $email";` (remove the dot `.`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put myemail and visitors emails in one array and then run a loop, the same message will be send to all in array.
e.g.

```
$aEmails = array();
$aEmails[] = 'myemail@something.com';
$aEmails[] = 'visitoremail@something.com';

foreach(aEmails AS aEmail){
mail($aEmail, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need 'visitoremail@something.com' to be a variable. That means it should be '$email' since every visitor will have a unique email. How do I achieve that using $email instead of visitoremail@something.com?

Comment: then just provide a form to fill and submit or login that visitor from any other site like facebook, twitter etc.. This is the only you can get his/her email.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just replaced "$aEmails[] = 'visitoremail@something.com';" with "$aEmails[] = $email';" and it's working!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any result then you must check your html forms'  tag it should have method="POST" attribute.

Then in here remove the dot

```
 $recipient = "myemail@mysite.com, .$email";
```

like this

```
$recipient = "myemail@mysite.com, $email";
```